# Unhandled Runtime Error in react class component when using async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-class-based-component

When I run `getData` in the following

```
const FunctionalComponent = observer(): JSX.Element => {
  const { userStore, authStore } = useStores()

  const getData = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const result = await userStore.findById(authStore.id)

    console.log('result in getData', result)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])
})
```

I `console.log`

```
{
  clientSettings: {test: 'hello'}
}
```

When I attempt run getData in a React class component like the following

```
class AUIGrid extends React.Component<Props, State> {

  getData = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const { userStore, authStore } = useStores()
    const result = await userStore.findById(authStore.id)

    console.log('result in getData', result)
  }

  saveColumnLayoutWithOrder = (): void => {
    this.getData()
  }
}
```

and run `saveColumnLayoutWithOrder` with

```
<button onClick={() => {this.saveColumnLayoutWithOrder()}}>save</button>
```

I get an `Unhandled Runtime Error`

[image]

Why am I getting this error?

`useStores` explanation edit:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StoresContext } from '../contexts'
import ContextProps from '@/interfaces/context-props'

const useStores = (): ContextProps => React.useContext(StoresContext)

export default useStores
```

Comment: What is `useStores`? Normally React hooks are not supposed to be used in class-based components.

Comment: @ghybs edited my post to explain what `useStores` is, but I'm beginning to think that I should not just use hooks in class based components..